# 3D camera to 3D model generation

Tags: 3d, photo, photos, 3d-modelling, 3d-model

Is it possible to generate a 3D model, to be imported in Unity/3ds Max/Maya from a 3D camera photo? Where can I find resources about this?

I would also like to know if you know any affordable 3D camera for this task, as everything that I've found so far are movie-driven $2000 and up 4K cameras. I just need some 10MP thing

Answer (score 0):

Such things exist but will not have good results in general and certainly will not be usable in a game (the meshes created by such tools have far too many tris and are normally an absolute mess of polygons for a modeler to try to cleanup). If you want models, you need to learn how to model or be willing to pay cash for models.